# Create a virtual machine using gitlab-ci

Tags: virtual-machine, gitlab-ci

How can I create a virtual machine (Centos-8) using a gitlab-ci.yml file?

No software needed to build the VM should be installed on the Gitlab runner. Binary software should also not be checked into git.

I can create docker images - for example for the use of Packer - in a prebuild step. This image can be cached in Artifactory.

But how should I handle that for the Centos image? 
During the installation using Packer, there`s a reboot required...

Comment: Where you want to create this VM? In VMware, Proxmox, somewhere in the cloud?

Comment: The VM should be created using a Gitlab-Runner (installed as a service in an private Openshift cluster) and stored as image (for example as qcow2) in Artifactory.